# What does an question (?) mark and dot (.) in dart language?

Tags: flutter, dart, null, option-type

say I defined ...

```
final DocumentSnapshot doc;
```

variable `doc` might be null so I use a question mark and dot...

```
print(widget.doc); // null
print(widget.doc == null); // true
print(widget.doc?.data['name']);
```

why `widget.doc?.data['name']` throw error `Tried calling: []("name")` instead returning `null`?

for my understanding `?.` to check whether `null` and if it so will return `null`

Comment: Could it be that `doc != null` but `data` is? In that case, `operator[]` will be called on a `null` object. Otherwise, you understood well what null-aware operators.

Comment: Drop an updoot on the github issue mentioned by Alexandre. We found why it happens, he told us how it happens. O_o

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the current version of Dart (2.3) *Null-aware access* doesn't short-circuit call chain.

So `a?.b.c` will throw an exception if `a` is null because it's the same as `(a != null ? a.b : null).c`.

In your case `widget.doc?.data['name']` is the same as `((e) { return e != null ? e.data : null; }(widget.doc))['name']`.

To make your code working you need to introduce a variable.

```
var a = widget.doc?.data;
print(a == null ? null : a['name']);
```

NB: you may be interested by [#36541: Map does not have a null-aware-chainable "get" method](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36541)

Comment: Was it the same in Dart 2.2?

Comment: Yes. It's even the same as Dart-1.12 :)

Comment: Also: [Null-aware subscript operator #28389](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28389)